# Table View Pull Refresh added to the bottom of the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pull-to-refresh

I was looking at `EGOTableViewPullRefresh` where when we hold down the `tableview`, and it gets refreshed.

I need to do the following;

I need the user to scroll to the bottom of the Table View and hold-on and then the page to add more records. Is this possible ?

**Update:**

In foursqure and twitter, we could hold the scroll for awhile and arrow signs gets displayed as the application refresh.

I need to implement something similar to this, but the user will have to go to the last record of the tableview and hold to display the arrow sign and it should display the next 10 records.

Comment: i think you are looking something like lazy loading kind of stuff for your app, can you elaborate a bit more about what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I have updated my question above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[look this](https://github.com/emenegro/bottom-pull-to-refresh) - Bottom Pull up to refresh manager